# messagebox not showing in winforms application c#

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, messagebox

When I try to initiate a message box (usually to notify of an exception, but I have tried to just initiate one from the form) the program seems to stall and I am unable to click anything except to close it but it has to be done from the visual studio window.

I have narrowed the problem down to something to do with the pictureBox1_paint event handler as when I remove this code the message boxes start to appear again. Here is the relevant code:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, mRect);
    }
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

The call stack shows that it is on some external code which when expanded seems to me that it is 'painting' the message box to the screen but seems to being held up by something? If the program is paused it shows the NEXT line to be executed is when it returns from whatever it is doing, an example shown below:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GlobalPlot != null)
    {
        resize = ExpandToBound(GlobalPlot.Size, pictureBox1.Size);
    }
    else return;

    try
    {
        PlotPixel(resize);

    }
    catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException index)
    {
        //this is the next line to execute:
        MessageBox.Show(index.Message,"Exception",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return;
    }
}
```

Not really sure what is going on, but any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: the try catch can be inside the first if, after the resize = ... statement so you dont need to use the ugly return statement. In fact you dont need it after the MessageBox.Show either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the messagebox will be there but under your form where you cannot see it.
Try this :

```
MessageBox.Show(this, index.Message,"Exception",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

When the messagebox appears it probably covers the picture, causing it to raise the paint event. In the paint event there is a call to Invalidate() which again raises the paint event, which will call Invalidate() again which again raises the paint event and this continues and makes your form appear frozen.

Remove the Invalidate() from the paint event.

Comment: In the Paint event, is the pictureBox1.Invalidate(); really neccesary ?

Comment: @JoeFletcher Does the Invalidate in your paint method not causes the Paint event to be called again ? And thus the Invalidate again and thus the Paint again and so on... causing the MessageBox.Show() and any other methods to have to wait and making your form appear frozen.

Comment: Ah, what a simple error, I think that has solved it. Thank you very much. I was thinking that needed to be called to make sure the rectangle was rendered and now it seems obvious.

Comment: No problem. If this answer solved it than please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Because this is the most viewed question with that topic, here is a real working resolution. Just fill all MessageBox parameters like 
MessageBox.Show(index.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);

Comment: Yes it works. But what is the reason behind it? Can you please explain it?

Comment: I believe the DefaultDesktopOnly option is what solves the issue. The other parameters are required because there's no shorter overload that includes the MessageBoxOptions parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue , and i solved it with calling the message box from forms:

Instead of calling

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("test","test");
```

call

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test","test");
```

Hope this helps